# Passing arguments to Shared Function - C

Tags: c, arguments, dlsym

I have used `dlopen` to load an object and `dlsym` to get a function pointer to a shared object function. Everything works fine. I have tested it calling then the shared function which (for now) only prints and it works-prints fine in the main program calling it. Now I want to pass two arguments to this function. An `int` and a `char *` .Can anyone help me understand how can I pass arguments to a shared function? I have searched in the web but I cannot understand how it works.

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of making the function have two parameters?

Comment: Yes firstly i have to modify the function prototype...I know this...But i don't know how to call it with arguments from the main program.

Comment: It shouldn't be any different than calling a function that isn't in a shared library.  Are you familiar with that?

Comment: The way you would call *any* function with arguments... e.g. func(arg1, arg2); or, in your case with an int and char*: func(666, "SpyrosR")

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Load the function:

```
int (*func)(int x, char *y) = dlsym(dl_handle, "your_function");
```

You might well decide you need a cast on the return from `dlsym()`; it is one of the uglinesses with dynamically loaded libraries.

Invoke it:

```
int i = 37;
char buffer[64];
int result1 = (*func)(i, buffer);  // Old school — pre-C89 (but still works and is explicit)
int result2 = func(i+1, buffer);   // New school — can leave you looking for the wrong thing.
```